# Map all routes that start with a specific URL part / keyword

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm building a test center for various unit tests on my personal library and I wanted to have an easy-to-access route for a test API. So I have two entries in my route config: the default and my custom route...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name:="Default",
            url:="{controller} / {Action} / {id}",
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name:="UnitTests",
                routeTemplate:="test/{category}/{testname}",
                defaults:=New With {.controller = "TestApis", .action = "testme",
                .category = "TestCategoryOne", .testname = UrlParameter.Optional}
            )
```

The idea was that whenever I want to make a call to my test API controller, I'll just prepend the URL with "test/" and it would know to redirect it to my "TestApisController" . . . but it seems to have broken my Default route.

### QUESTION

Is there a way by which I can map all routes that start with "test/" to a specific controller while at the same time *not* breaking my default route?

### EDIT

So after some time, I realized that the reason this method wasn't working had nothing to do with the route. I had another default API route defined in the "WebApiConfig" file that was causing some issues. I apologize, I am still transitioning from Webforms to MVC.

Comment: I am slightly confused, `MapHttpRoute` does not exist in MVC 6? The closest I know is adding the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` which allows you to use `routes.MapWebApiRoute`. In any case, why don't you add your route as a standard route (since you are defining a controller and an action) with `routes.MapRoute`, and declare it before the default route (as the test route is more specific than the default one)?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I am using MapHttpRoute because the controller I am trying to call is a Web API controller. It doesn't seem to work otherwise.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. And that was my mistake regarding the MVC 6 tag. I am using MVC version 5.2

Comment: You will need to swap the order of the routes `../test/someCategory/someTestName` will go to the `someCategory` method of `testController` passing `someTestName` to the `id` parameter because it matches the first (default) route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the controller you're trying to route to is a Web Api controller you'll want to put your custom route in the `WebApiConfig.vb` file.  The route should then go above the default route in that file because it is more specific than the default route, as @Stephen Muecke noted.  Your original code would change a bit, instead of `routes.MapHttpRoute` you would have `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`, like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
    name:="UnitTests", _
    routeTemplate:="test/{category}/{testname}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "TestApis", .action = "testme", .category = "TestCategoryOne", .testname = UrlParameter.Optional}
)
```

I've done this same thing when I wanted to route to specific controllers in some situations and also included custom authentication handlers on the route, what you're trying to do should work.